# How to fix file_get_contents() warning: Failed to open stream?

Tags: php, apache, fopen

I don't know why but I always got this error when I want to get PHP data with file_get_contents.

I have checked my PHP.ini and allow_url_fopen is: ON so that couldn't be the problem.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
$id='54352';
$url='http://www.google.com';
$data = file_get_contents('http://www.####.###/###.php?id='.$id.'&url='.urlencode($url));

var_dump($data);
```

I don't know what is going on here, I just get this error message and the value: bool(false).

I have also tried cURL, but it doesn't return ANY value to me.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: well whatever url you requests is returning a 500 status code... whats there to wonder about?

Comment: But it SHOULD work, a lot of people using it, I don't think that url would be bad.

Comment: shoulda coulda woulda :) ether your request url is not well formed or whatever you call returns a 500 for whatever reason

Comment: have you tried to access the URL in a browser? what do you get then?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
 $data = file_get_contents('http://www.####.###/###.php?id='.$id.'&url='.urlencode($url),true);
```

Comment: sorry I have miswritten it in this code, but its like var_dump($data) in my original code...